# Beam WordCount TaskManagerFailure NoClassDefFoundError for MetricUpdates$MetricUpdate

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I am trying to run the Beam (2.21) WordCount example on Flink 1.10.1 using docker images. The runtime job manager and taskmanager starts fine but fails at the last step of writing the results with the following Exception:

```
taskmanager_1  | 2020-07-06 21:18:31,897 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.accumulators.AccumulatorRegistry     - Failed to serialize accumulators for task.
taskmanager_1  | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/beam/runners/core/metrics/MetricUpdates$MetricUpdate
taskmanager_1  |        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1629)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:520)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
taskmanager_1  |        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1413)
```

Any pointer what might be missing here?

Comment: If I  instead put the Beam WordCount jar in the "/opt/flink-1.10.1/lib" dir as follows,  
  
$ ls  
flink-dist_2.12-1.10.1.jar  
flink-table-blink_2.12-1.10.1.jar  
flink-table_2.12-1.10.1.jar         
log4j-1.2.17.jar                  
 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar          
 word-count-beam-bundled-0.1.jar  
  
It runs without any Exception!

Is this the expected behavior? Do we need to always bundle the job-jar in the same lib location as other flink jars?

Comment: Hi there Avijit Saha, did you pursue this error any further or did you find further insught into this? I'm having the same problem. Best regards